# Rails fails to do db:migrate, database is locked & no schema migrations table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rake, database-schema

So I played around with rails a few weeks ago, and then I came back yesterday for some more dabbling, and tada, nothing works.
For some reason, I keep getting this issue.

I've tried everything I can think of:

- Deleting and remaking the project
- Uninstalling gems
- Creating the project in RubyMine
- Creating the project on the command line
- Running db:migrate while the server is running (passenger)
- Running db:migrate while the server is not running
- Recreating the project and running db:migrate before running the server at all

I am very frustrated and sad at this point, because I am on the verge of giving up on rails because of this, I just can not find a solution.

My setup is I have a windows PC with my rails app in a share drive that I access on my laptop, which is running ubuntu.
I thought there might be something wrong here, but when I run the server, it works just fine, I can create controllers and views and play around with them in chrome, but anything to do with the database is just absolutely f***ed and I can't understand why what-so-ever.
Here is the stack trace I get when I run db:migrate --trace:

---

```
rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in 'step'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in 'block in each'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in 'loop'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in 'each'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:152:in 'map'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:152:in 'block in execute'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:95:in 'prepare'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:137:in 'execute'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:255:in 'block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in 'block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in 'yield_shares'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in 'permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:254:in 'block in execute'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:579:in 'block (2 levels) in log'
/home/kalin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in 'mon_synchronize'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:578:in 'block in log'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in 'instrument'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:569:in 'log'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:253:in 'execute'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:311:in 'create_table'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:29:in 'create_table'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1187:in 'initialize'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in 'new'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in 'up'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1011:in 'migrate'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:in 'migrate'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in 'block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in 'block in execute'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in 'each'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in 'execute'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in 'block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/kalin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in 'mon_synchronize'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in 'invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:182:in 'invoke'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in 'invoke_task'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in 'block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in 'each'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in 'block in top_level'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in 'run_with_threads'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in 'top_level'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in 'block in run'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in 'standard_exception_handling'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in 'run'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in '<top (required)>'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rake:23:in 'load'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rake:23:in '<main>'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in 'eval'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in '<main>'

Caused by:
SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in 'step'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in 'block in each'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in 'loop'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in 'each'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:152:in 'map'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:152:in 'block in execute'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:95:in 'prepare'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:137:in 'execute'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:255:in 'block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in 'block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in 'yield_shares'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in 'permit_concurrent_loads'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:254:in 'block in execute'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:579:in 'block (2 levels) in log'
/home/kalin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in 'mon_synchronize'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:578:in 'block in log'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in 'instrument'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:569:in 'log'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:253:in 'execute'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:311:in 'create_table'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:29:in 'create_table'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1187:in 'initialize'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in 'new'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in 'up'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1011:in 'migrate'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:in 'migrate'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in 'block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in 'block in execute'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in 'each'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in 'execute'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in 'block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/kalin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in 'mon_synchronize'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in 'invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:182:in 'invoke'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in 'invoke_task'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in 'block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in 'each'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in 'block in top_level'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in 'run_with_threads'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in 'top_level'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in 'block in run'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in 'standard_exception_handling'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in 'run'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in '<top (required)>'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rake:23:in 'load'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rake:23:in '<main>'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in 'eval'
/home/kalin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in '<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: Try deleting the file `db/development.sqlite3` while the application is not running, then run `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Well, it was refreshing to finally see a different error for once, but it still failed

---
CantOpenException: unable to open database file

Comment: Now I closed the server and tried to run it, and its giving me the same thing as before ;(

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it probably has something to do with going over the network (I tried making it locally on my laptop and it worked). I was doing it this way before, and it worked just fine, but obviously when I changed some of my pc components out, it no longer wants to work for some reason. This makes no sense, because the share drive lets me access the files, delete the files, create new ones and everything.